# How does git pull request work in Azure ? I observe the branches that should be deleted on remote, right?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am a bit superficial user of GIT, and just have started using Azure at work.
Soon I will have to work with my colleagues on one project and I do not understand how pull request button works on the Azure webpage. The history of commits:

- main & dev branches
- pull request of dev into main
  using **Rebase and fast-forward** option on the Azure webpage & **delete the dev branch**
- created dev2 branch
  from main
- committed new changes to  dev2 branch, pushed to remote
- pull request
  of dev2 into main similarly to the previous time

What I observe on the Azure webpage is a perfect single branch as expected ( Azure deletes old branches), however,

*why do I still see **dev** and **dev2** branches on remote?*

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  origin/dev
  origin/dev2
  origin/main
```

I read [the related Azure page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops) but I found nothing related there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you rebase and fast-forward the pull request means that the changes will be rewritten onto master, and that's the reason that you see a single branch.

This has nothing to do with deleting branches or not, which is an entirely different option when completing a pull request.

You can have a visible merge commit *and* a deleted branch, as well as you can have a linear history *and* a visible branch. Again, they're different, unrelated things, both in Git and Azure pull requests.

See the section [Complete the pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#complete-the-pull-request):

> 4. Select any of the following post-completion options (some options are not available depending on the merge type):
>
> - ....
> - Delete `<branch name>` after merging to delete the source branch from the pull request.

Comment: thanks! But why do I still see those non-main branches on remote ( origin), if I selected to delete option in Azure? ( I have also edited the question, I indeed chose Delete <branch name> after merging)